# Placing Lat/Long on a azimuthalEqualArea map with D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geo

I'm trying to plot some lat/long points onto a map, but I can't get them to appear in the correct place.

The dots should be in San Francisco. I have a [JSfiddle of the code](http://jsfiddle.net/edlea/vsykp61e/3/).

[image: Points on Globe]

```
var width = 400,
    height = 400;

var projection = d3.geo.azimuthalEqualArea()
    .clipAngle(180 - 1e-3)
    .scale(100)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
    .precision(.1);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var graticule = d3.geo.graticule();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg.append("defs").append("path")
    .datum({type: "Sphere"})
    .attr("id", "sphere")
    .attr("d", path);

svg.append("use")
    .attr("class", "stroke")
    .attr("xlink:href", "#sphere");

svg.append("use")
    .attr("class", "fill")
    .attr("xlink:href", "#sphere");

svg.append("path")
    .datum(graticule)
    .attr("class", "graticule")
    .attr("d", path);

d3.json("http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4090846/world-50m.json", function(error, world) {
    svg.insert("path", ".graticule")
        .datum(topojson.feature(world, world.objects.land))
        .attr("class", "land")
        .attr("d", path);

    svg.insert("path", ".graticule")
        .datum(topojson.mesh(world, world.objects.countries, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
        .attr("class", "boundary")
        .attr("d", path);

});

var latlong = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[37.3838312,-122.0423922]},"properties":{"timestampMs":1415894666875}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[37.3838474,-122.0423972]},"properties":{"timestampMs":1415894601718}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[37.3838474,-122.0423972]},"properties":{"timestampMs":1415894536288}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[37.3838411,-122.0424015]},"properties":{"timestampMs":1415894471356}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[37.383878,-122.0423925]},"properties":{"timestampMs":1415894406257}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[37.3838317,-122.0423856]},"properties":{"timestampMs":1415894326769}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[37.3838287,-122.0423933]},"properties":{"timestampMs":1415894261810}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[37.383829,-122.0423847]},"properties":{"timestampMs":1415894196224}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[37.3838765,-122.0424141]},"properties":{"timestampMs":1415894131768}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[37.3838177,-122.0423668]},"properties":{"timestampMs":1415894066809}}]};

// THESE ARE THE POINTS THAT ARE NOT BEING PLACED CORRECTLY
svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(latlong.features).enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function (d) { return projection(d.geometry.coordinates)[1]; })
    .attr("cy", function (d) { return projection(d.geometry.coordinates)[0]; })
    .attr("r", "2px")
    .attr("fill", "red");
```

Comment: Have you just got your lat/long the wrong way round? They're usually output as long/lat so cx will take [0] and cy [1].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've specified the latitude and longitude the wrong way round for d3.geo and you're also taking the output the wrong way round. It is counter to the way that they are displayed by convention (N/S then E/W) but it is more consistent with a drawing convention of across then up/down.

From [path.projection](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths#path_projection) in the D3 API Geo reference:

> A projection function takes a two-element array of numbers
>   representing the coordinates of a location, [longitude, latitude], and
>   returns a similar two-element array of numbers representing the
>   projected pixel position [x, y].

To fix this, I've reversed the coordinates of your FeatureCollection:

```
var latlong = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
    {"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-122.0423922,37.3838312]},"properties":{"timestampMs":1415894666875}},
etc...
```

and reversed the coordinates of your plot.

```
    .attr("cx", function (d) { return projection(d.geometry.coordinates)[0]; })
    .attr("cy", function (d) { return projection(d.geometry.coordinates)[1]; })
```

Everything else was fine. Amended [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vsykp61e/4/) here. So often it's the little things!

Comment: ah, I didn't even think to swap the coords within in GeoJson data first, makes total sense! Thank you :)

Comment: One small extra observation. You can combine the cx and cy into one transform statement which can make your code shorter: .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate("+projection(d.geometry.coordinates)+")"; })